# Shortcut with Inno Setup for file extensions with more then 3 characters

Tags: icons, inno-setup, shortcut

Simple question, I'm trying to create shortcut for .xlsx file in Inno Setup by using this code in [Icon] section:

```
[Icons]
Name: "{group}\Name"; Filename: "M:\name.xlsx"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; IconFilename: "{app}\name.ico"
```

As a result I'm getting shortcut to **name.xls** file. Does Inno Setup understands file extensions with more then 3 characters?

Comment: Your code works correctly. No way it could not. Didn't you had a shortcut to .xls there before? Start menu is heavily cached and it's not easy to update existing shortcuts. Try to change `{group}\Name` to `{group}\Name2`. - And btw, Start menu groups shall not be used ever since Windows 7, according to Microsoft guidelines.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thanks Martin, but I tried it different way. I added extension as ".12345" and got as a result shortcut to file: "Name.123". So, there is 100% something with 3 characters restrictions for extension names. Did you tried to test your suggestion?

Comment: Of course I did test it. It works as expected. How do you test what the shortcut target is like? What is your version of Windows? What is your file system? Both C: and M:? What if you create a shortcut to a .xmls file on C: drive?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl That's strange, but shortcut for C:\Name.xmls works as expected, but if I will change drive letter to "M" - I will get the M:\Name.xml. I tested it on Windows 7 and Windows 10, both are NTFS. I'm looking to Properties of shortcut in order to check file path.

Comment: What is M:? Is it a mapped network drive?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl yes, is a network Drive, which is permanently mapped on PC

Comment: Works for me even with a network drive. Can you post an installer log file?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Can you please point me where I can find Log file?

Comment: `mysetup.exe /log=c:\path\to\install.log`

Comment: @MartinPrikryl 2017-09-19 10:53:17.669   Installing the file.
2017-09-19 10:53:17.685   Successfully installed the file.
2017-09-19 10:53:17.685   -- Icon entry --
2017-09-19 10:53:17.685   Dest filename: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\test\name.lnk
2017-09-19 10:53:17.685   Creating the icon.
2017-09-19 10:53:17.997   Successfully created the icon.
2017-09-19 10:53:18.324   Installation process succeeded.
2017-09-19 10:53:18.324   Need to restart Windows? No
2017-09-19 10:53:19.182   Deinitializing Setup.
2017-09-19 10:53:19.198   Log closed.

Comment: Hm, that does not show anything unfortunately. - Did you try creating the link using [`CreateShellLink` Pascal function](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createshelllink)?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I tried to avoid any usage of [Code] section, but it seems that there is no other way, if Inno Setup cannot correctly execute link creation in [Icon] section, at least in my case. Thanks, Martin, for your help.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Just fyi, when I'm using [Code] section - I'm getting the same result: only 3 characters in extension for Network Drive, and more than 3 characters for local files. Mysticism.

Comment: `CreateShellLink` passes the `ShortcutTo` argument directly to Windows API ([`IShellLink::SetPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761052.aspx)). So this does not look like an issue of Inno Setup at all. Are you even able to create the shortcut manually (in Windows Explorer)?